# Dynamically bind objects to inputs in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I have these objects right here that I will use to save data from a form, and later send it to an api as JSON :

```
$scope.price = {} 
$scope.item = {"price":$scope.price, };
```

I also have these field which will be used to dynamically generate inputs on a html page:

```
$scope.fields = [
    {
        name: $scope.item.title,
        title: 'Title',
        type: {
            view: 'input'
        }
    },
    {
        name: $scope.price.regular,
        title: 'Regualar Price',
        type: {
            view: 'input'
        }
    }        
];
```

Now in order to generate the form I use this code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in fields">
            <label>{{ field.title }}:</label>  
            <span ng-switch on="field.type.view">  
                <span ng-switch-when="input">  
                    <input  
                              ng-model=field.name
                              type="text"  
                              />  
                </span>  
            </span>
        </div>
```

And with this code, it is not assigning the values in the input to the objects. Is there a way to do it? I know I can do it this way:

```
ng-model="item[field.name]"
```

But that limits me to only one level of the object. I want to be able to bind nested objects. And I just can't seem to figure it out. Thank You!

Comment: there is already a directive to build forms from a JSON Schema object; see http://schemaform.io/.

Comment: You can't simply generate fields with `ng-repeat`. See this post and particularly this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631700/how-to-create-an-array-with-angularjss-ng-model/21644599#21644599
You need to use `$compile` to insert your fields with a directive.