# html input name="foo[]" in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry cant think of a more valid title. In HTML when we want multiple values for a given name we use this `name="foo[]"` attribute.

When the data is posted it comes as an array. What I want is this functionality with `ng-model` in angular.

**Reason:** I have a form that has multiple fields with same name, like in a CV when we write our past experiences.

**NB:** Before saying this is a duplicate, please read this properly. I have seen valid questions being marked as duplicate and not constructive.

Comment: Did u try with something like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631700/how-to-create-an-array-with-angularjss-ng-model ?

Comment: In angular it does not matter what name input has (names are mainly used only for validation purposes). If creating CV form, you shall write `ng-repeat="experience in experiences"` and inside it write something like this: `<input type="text" ng-model="experience.from"/>`. `$scope.experiences = [...]`. If you want to add more experience you should add another object to `$scope.experiences` array.

Comment: To complete @karaxuna answer you just need to manage a collection (with some "add" and "remove" buttons) using a ng-repeat.

Comment: @Mindastic I didn't find that. Couldn't make up words for this thing. -.-'
Its some what near to what I want but I don't want to be a numbered thing unless its the only way

Comment: I am not using ng-repeat actually. but this seems like a nice idea. Using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in your angular controller you have something like this:

```
$scope.foo = []; //your values in the array
```

You can have in your view something like this:

```
<dd ng-repeat="item in foo">
    <input type="text" ng-model="foo[$index]" value="{{item}}" required/>
</dd>
```

This is what you need? No need for name if you use ng-model you have the data in the model on form submit.

Comment: Its not an ng-repeat thing. Im not using ng-repeat. I am adding it via jQuery append and $complie.

Comment: @echo_salik That's probably why you can't achieve that. You shouldn't jQuery within angular at all.

Comment: I am new to angular actually. This way, creating an array seems the best way, is the best idea yet. Thanks all.

Comment: You try to create an angular app but you think in jquery :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background