# Sending multiple parameters data in single array in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

All i am doing is making a week calendar type (Sun, Mon, Tue...) with their start time and stop time... format in html and sending to DB

front view

[image]

Here this is the view.. suppose when a user wanted to set his work timing.. sun 1:PM to 4:00 PM and in monday 10:00AM to 6:00PM

how to send data like this `{"Schedule":["sunday","01:00","04:00"],["monday","10:00","05:00"]}`

Comment: You should use `model` as `array` in this case. Declare `$scope.data = [];` in controller and assign the `index` at run time.

Comment: any plukner or material to read it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631700/how-to-create-an-array-with-angularjss-ng-model

Comment: and what about the data sending part?

Comment: I guess once you assign the values in `model array` you can use it anywhere