# Using Angular, Trying to Save An Array to the Rails Backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, arrays, postgresql

I tried several methods I found online but none worked and they weren't specifically targeting the problems I'm having. Basically I have a recipes Rails app, and using Angular, I have to:
(1) Allow the user to add one or more ingredients and directions in the form, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/V4BqE/
(2) Save the ingredients and directions as an array data type in the Rails database (I'm using postgresql), sort of like this but without using $scope: [How to create an Array with AngularJS's ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631700/how-to-create-an-array-with-angularjss-ng-model)

Schema:

```
  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "difficulty"
    t.integer  "time"
    t.integer  "servings"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "ingredients",              array: true
    t.string   "directions",               array: true
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

Controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function NewRecipeController ($location, RecipeService, CategoryService) {
        var vm = this;

        CategoryService.getCategories()
            .then(function(response) {
                vm.categories = response.data;
            });

      vm.addRecipe = function() {
        var data = {
            title: this.title,
            difficulty: this.difficulty,
            time: this.time,
            servings: this.servings,
            description: this.description,
            // Im stuck trying to figure out the following 2 lines
            ingredients: this.ingredients,
            directions: this.directions,
            category_id: this.category.id
        };

        RecipeService.createRecipe(data);
        $location.path('profile');
      };

    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('NewRecipeController', NewRecipeController)

}());
```

Form (just the ingredients and directions section are relevant):

```
        <form name="newRecipe" novalidate ng-submit="vm.addRecipe()">

            <!-- title -->

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Recipe Name</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" ng-model="vm.title" required>
            </div>

            <!-- category -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="category" ng-model="vm.category" ng-options="category.name for category in vm.categories" required></select>
            </div>

            <!-- description -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" ng-model="vm.description" required>
            </div>

            <!-- difficulty -->

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="difficulty">Difficulty</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number" name="difficulty" ng-model="vm.difficulty" min="1" max="5" required>
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter a number between 1 and 5.</small>
            </div>

            <!-- time -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="time">Time to Make (Minutes)</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number" name="time" ng-model="vm.time" min="5" step="5" required>
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter a number that is an increment of 5 minutes.</small>
            </div>

            <!-- servings -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="servings">Servings</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="number" name="servings" ng-model="vm.servings" required>
            </div>

            <!-- ingredients - this is where I'm stuck -->
            <!-- I want to be able to let the user add more input fields if they want and do the same for directions -->

            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="ingredient in vm.ingredients">
                <label for="ingredients">Ingredients</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ingredients" ng-model="vm.ingredients[$index]" required>
            </div>

            <div ng-show="newRecipe.$valid">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create Recipe">
            </div>
        </form>
```

I understand that I have to save the array as a string. I tried directly saving `ingredients: '["ingredient1", "ingredient2"]'` and `ingredients: '["ingredient1, ingredient2"]'`, but both just saved as `ingredients: ["ingredient1"]`. I've also tried `JSON.stringify(ingredients)`. I am using a serializer:

```
class RecipeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :difficulty, :time, :servings, :description, :ingredients, :directions

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  # has_many :favorites
    has_many :favorited_users, through: :favorites, source: :user
end
```

Recipe Rails controller #create:

```
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    @recipe.author = current_user
    @recipe.save
  end
```

Full code on Github: https://github.com/auranbuckles/world-recipes

Comment: could be helpful to see more of your angular code. Putting together a fiddle of what you have already would be awesome!

Comment: Doublecheck the Rails "Recipe" model; there should be something in it that looks like `serialize :ingredients, Array` and `serialize :directions, Array`. Also track down the Rails controller that this is being submitted to; there should be a method that extracts the recipe params before it's saved; that'd also be useful for debugging this.

Comment: (you should be able to submit `ingredients: '["ingredient1", "ingredient2"]` if the Rails model and controller are set up correctly, that's why I'm asking to see those too)

Comment: Thanks! I added more of my code and the link to the github repo. Just experimented with `serialize :ingredients, Array` in the model. In this case, if I send `ingredients: '["ingredient1", "ingredient2"]'` to the backend, I get the error `ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch in RecipesController#create` `Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "[\"ingredient1\", \"ingredient2\"]"`. And if I send a plain array `ingredients: ["ingredient1", "ingredient2"]` I get a blank [] array sent to the backend. I'm still stuck but I'll keep testing this out.