# Can ng-model replace Ids?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to avoid IDs while creating elements i.e. using ng-model it is easier to validate form fields and other stuff?

```
<div ng-repeat="x in TestData">
   <input type="text" id="nameField-{{$index}}"/>
</div>
```

The above code will display the number of input boxes equal to the length of the TestData array where every text box will have a unique id `"nameField-0", "nameField-1"` and so on, using these IDs we can take the textbox values, validate the fields etc.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in TestData">
   <input type="text" ng-model=""/> <!-- what shall be done here to have unique IDs -->
</div>
```

Although going with IDs is working fine for me but as far as I can understand If I use IDs then that will not be a pure angular way (or IDs cannot be replaced by mg-models), correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: how about using <input type="text" ng-model="x.text"/>

Comment: I went through some links and they say this thing you've mentioned above. But one question: So say if the user enters "ABC123" and I am using some regex in js and I want to accept only "ABCDJAHJD" i.e. alphabets. How do I show a red border around that textbox for which he has entered invalid input?

Comment: IDs allow uniquely identifying an element in the DOM. ng-model is used to bind an input to an element of your model. They are completely unrelated. I don't understand what you're asking. If you need IDs for a reason or another (angular doesn't care about IDs), then add an ID. If you want to use angular bidirectional binding of your form inputs, use ng-model. If you want to do both, add an ID and use ng-model.

Comment: for that purpose i would recommend you to build a custom directive or filter

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for the clarification. This is what I was trying to understand, using IDs and ng-model together is not violating the rules.

Comment: @u_8398 regarding your additional, unrelated question in your last comment, use ng-pattern, and add `input.ng-invalid { border: 1px solid red; }` to your stylesheet.

Comment: If you work in an enterprise environment and dev in that kind of system, you'll find your automation test teams would love you to keep the id's in as they often use them.

Comment: @M14: So if I create a custom directive (a directive that checks for only alphabets then again small query, how will we identify for which input element we have to show an error border, if the input is invalid)?

Comment: @u_8398 ng-repeat will create separate scope in each iteration, so it wont be difficult to take the particular element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an Array with AngularJS's ng-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631700/how-to-create-an-array-with-angularjss-ng-model)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to grab element with id/name/etc. You can use `ng-model` to bind your values and `ng-pattern` to validate them.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in testData">
  <ng-form name="tForm">
    <input type="text" name="tInput" ng-model="x.name" ng-pattern="/^[A-Z]*$/" />
    <span ng-if="tForm.tInput.$error.pattern" style="color:red">Invalid!</span>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

See this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/murumayubi/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add this,

```
$scope.nameField = [];
```

in ng-reapeat add this,

```
<div ng-repeat="x in TestData">
   <input type="text" ng-model="nameField[$index]"/>
</div>
```

`nameField` will be an array with all your values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="x in TestData" ng-init='this["nameField-"+x]'>
    <input ng-model='this["nameField-"+x]'/>
</div>
```

You use ng-init to add new variables to the controller, "this" refer to your scope, and since the scope is an object, since this[bla] == this.bla tou are actually saying, add to my scope a variable name "nameField=" and you add the x value.
after you have created your variable, just use it in the same way in your ng-model.

If you want to show your variable's value in any div/span, just use it via ng-bind:

```
<div ng-bind='this["nameField-"+x]'></div>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.