# angularjs adding an item to array without $index key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input name="options[{{$index}}]"  ng-repeat="n in [] | range:count"
       ng-model="field.options[$index].value" >
```

in the conttroller

```
$scope.field.options = [];
```

when i add item to array it s saving them with key.

```
"options":{"0":{"value":"sdfas"},"1":{"value":"sdfsdf"},"2":{"value":"sdfasdf"}}
```

I wanna remove that "0" "1" ..

the reason i wanna remove the key is i think my api not work because of this keys.
When i post my objcet like:

```
List<someobject> options;
```

and someobject class has only `value` field.

Comment: How do you add them to the array?

Comment: @Jimenemex I thought like ng-modal adding it ? when i put this {{$scope.fieldModalVM.field.options}} to view it s showing what it inside

Comment: Include how you add it with the `modal` and what `{{ $scope.fieldModalVm.field.options }}` spits out

Comment: Only reason why I'm asking is because it looks like you are `push`ing into the array an object that has a `value` variable instead of pushing the actual **value** of the `value` variable itself into the array.

Comment: field.options is just empty array. when i write something inside that input could it be store in ooptions array? that s what i m trying to do.

Comment: I wanna do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631700/how-to-create-an-array-with-angularjss-ng-model

Comment: then maybe problem is about how i pass object to modal. fieldModalVM: function() {
                            return {
                                field: {
                                    options: []
                                }
                            };
                        }

Comment: oh finally works. the problem is I forget to initialize an empty array in somewhere of my code. now it saving as i want

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. The code works in this [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/80aQVhLviQe7TrMhzpUG?p=preview).